# Subclassing and generics in C#

Tags: c#

I want to subclass a large number of classes so that they will all contain a certain set of the same properties. What would be the right way to do it in order to avoid repetition? I thought of using generics like:

```
public class SuperT<T> : T
{
    //the same set of properties
}
```

But the compiler says

> Cannot derive from 'T' because it is a type parameter

EDIT: I am trying to subclass some classes in a third party assembly so I cannot use a base class.

For example, the types are "Image", "Label", "Button" etc and I want to subclass them all to contain a property like "Radius". (So that I would use SuperImage element in XAML and when I set it's Radius property from XAML, I will be able to run some certain logic.)

One other way I just thought of right now is using T4 templates. I wonder if there is a way to do this with generics without resorting to templates? I cannot understand why the compiler rejects it.

Comment: Inheritance and Generics are two completely different concepts. It sounds like you really just want to leverage inheritance.

Comment: Use a base class or an Interface. Generics is not the "right tool for the job" in this case.

Comment: I am trying to subclass some classes in a third party assembly so I cannot use a base class.

Comment: Are you trying to add a base type to classes that already exist in a third party assembly?

Comment: `I am trying to subclass some classes in a third party assembly so I cannot use a base class.` - then create a wrapper/proxy that encapsulates that class and inherit from that.

Comment: Can you please clarify with some examples - it's hard to understand what you're trying to do here.

Comment: @FacticiusVir Yes, I guess we can say that.

Comment: @AntP I just added an example.

Comment: I've given you an example of `has-a` inheritance that you can use with third party libs.

Comment: Do these classes `Image`, `Label`, `Button` all share a common base class in the 3rd party library?

Comment: Can you use an extension method to statically add the `Radius` member as a method?

Comment: @JohnL. you're trying to *superclass* them, not *subclass* them - and the answer is simply "you can't," - I'm suspicious of why you'd want to do this (sounds like misguided deduplication to me) but if you really have a good reason you'll have to map these types to your own types with a common parent class (or interface).

Comment: @Igor Yes they share common base classes but I cannot add anything new to them.

Comment: Then you could write an extension method to "fake" extend these classes (see my answer below). Other than that you cannot extend them unless. The only other alternative is to wrap these 3rd party library types in your own types and extend those as you see fit but this could be a lot of work depending on what is exposed and how you are using it.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think generics have anything to do with this, however inheritance is probably what you're looking for.

There are two types of inheritance that you can use to subclass, and extension methods work to "superclass"... sort of.

1. Is-A inheritance
2. Has-A inheritance
3. And to simply add a similar method to a bunch of third party objects, you'll use an extension method.

---

### Is-A inheritance

Use a base class if you've got similar method implementations.

```
public abstract class BaseFoo {

    public void Bar() {
         // actual code
    }
}

public class Foo : BaseFoo
{
}
```

```
var foo = new Foo();
foo.Bar();
```

Use an Interface if you need to implement the same method on each class.

```
public interface IFoo {
    void Bar();
}

public class Foo : IFoo {
    public override void Bar(){
        // bar implementation
    }
}
```

```
var foo = new Foo();
foo.Bar();
```

Combining the two is also allowed, but you can only inherit on base class, where you can inherit multiple interfaces.

---

### Has-A inheritance

This is particularly useful with dependency injection, but it's simply the notion that you have an instance of another class to work with. It's essentially a wrapper class for you to work with.

```
public class Foo {
    private readonly ThirdPartyFoo _tpFoo;
    void Foo(ThirdPartyFoo tpFoo) {
        _tpFoo = tpFoo;
    }

    public void Bar(){
        // now I can do something with _tpFoo;
       _tpFoo.Bar(); 
    }
}
```

```
var tpFoo = new ThirdPartyFoo();
var foo = new Foo(tpFoo);
foo.Bar(); // invokes the underlying tpFoo
```

---

Lastly, if you just need to add a method to existing classes, then you create an extension method.

```
public static class ViewExtensions() 
{
    // this assumes your Image, Button, Label all inherit from View.
    public static Whatever Radius(this View view) {
        // do your radius work.
    }

}
```

Comment: This doesn't address the crux of the question, which is that he effectively wants to superclass existing third-party types.

Comment: @AntP if he can't inherit from the third party lib, he'll need to wrap it. That's the essence of has-a inheritance.

Comment: @AntP... basically his initial question was only whether to go with generics or inheritance. Later he modified with a scenario

Comment: @ChaseFlorell I don't necessarily disagree but the use case is still very vague - this sounds like a misguided "duplication is bad" thing to me - the types are inherently different things.

Comment: yeah, I see where he's coming from though. Generics don't make sense here, but the possibility of an extension method "might". `and I want to subclass them all to contain a property like "radius".`... See my edit.

Comment: maybe - again, though, the use case isn't clear so it's really impossible to suggest a solution that isn't loaded with speculation

Answer (score 1):

If these classes all share a common base class or common interface you could write an extension method.

```
public static class ShapeExetnsionsExtLib
{
    public static double Radius(this ShapeBase shape){
        return /*calculate radious*/;
    }
}
```

---

*From comments*

> I am trying to subclass some classes in a third party assembly so I cannot use a base class.
>
> For example, the the types are "Image", "Label", "Button" etc and I want to subclass them all to contain a property like "radius".
>
> Yes they share common base classes but I cannot add anything new to them.

Answer (score 0):

Just Use a base class:

```
public class Base
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

And inherite from it:

```
public class A : Base
{

}

public class B : Base
{

}
```

Comment: I am trying to subclass some classes in a third party assembly so I cannot use a base class.

Answer (score 0):

In general, you want to use one of the answers already posted about using a base class and inheriting from that. However, if the classes are in a third party library and are marked as `sealed`, then you will need to create a wrapper class to use as a base class.

*(Note that this option is a workaround and doesn't truly inherit from the third party class, so things in that class that are marked as `protected` won't be accessible without a liberal use of reflection.)*

```
// The sealed class within another library
public sealed ThirdPartyClass
{
    public ThirdPartyClass(int i) { }

    public int SomeProperty { get; set; }

    public int SomeMethod(string val) { return 0; }

    public static void SomeStaticMethod() { }
}

// The wrapper class to use as a pseudo base class for ThirdPartyClass
public class BaseClass
{
    private ThirdPartyClass _obj;

    public BaseClass(int i) { _obj = new ThirdPartyClass(i); }

    public int SomeProperty
    {
        get { return _obj.SomeProperty; }
        set { _obj.SomeProperty = value; }
    }

    public int SomeMethod(string val) { return _obj.SomeMethod(val); }

    public static SomeStaticMethod() { ThirdPartyClass.SomeStaticMethod(); }
}

// The child class that inherits from the "base" BaseClass
public class ChildClass : BaseClass
{

}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, this might be a logical problem. What if you are going to extend a **sealed class**? Or Int32 class? **Delegate**?

Anyway, the way I recommend is to create an interface and implement all the functions you need in the subclass.